# Dirac Delta definition in non-standard analysis?

Tags: nonstandard-analysis, dirac-delta

What is the definition of Dirac Delta in non-standard analysis?

I would define it either as a standard distribution with $\sigma=\epsilon$ or maximum equal to $\omega$. Which is the correct answer?

Comment: They mention an article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Infinitesimal_delta_functions), which might be worth pursuing.

Answer (score 5):

Just like in standard analysis where there are lots of ways to represent the Dirac delta distribution as a limit of a sequence, in nonstandard analysis there are lots of ways to represent the Dirac delta as a nonstandard function.

The simplest is probably to pick an infinite $H$ and set

$$ d(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & |x| > \frac{1}{2H}
\\ H & |x| \leq \frac{1}{2H} \end{cases} $$

Convolving $d$ with any *standard* continuous function gives

$$ \begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d(x) f(x) \, dx &= H \int_{-\frac{1}{2H}}^{\frac{1}{2H}} f(x) \, dx 
\\&= H f(\epsilon) \int_{-\frac{1}{2H}}^{\frac{1}{2H}} 1 \, dx 
\\&= H f(\epsilon) \frac{1}{H}
\\&= f(\epsilon)
\\&\approx f(0)
\end{align}$$

where I've used the mean value theorem to go from line one to line two. (one could instead use $|f(x) - f(0)| < e$ for $|x| < \frac{1}{2H}$ if they liked)

Comment: How would u differentiate such delta function?

Comment: @Anixx: You would use a different representative if you were seeking to differentiate it. I think anything nonnegative with area $\approx 1$ over an interval $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ and area $\approx 0$ over $(\epsilon, \infty)$ and $(-\infty, \epsilon)$ will do.

Comment: this has only a few properties of Dirac Delta and does not have others (i.e. differentiability).

Comment: @Anixx: Everything the dirac delta distribution is follows from the formula for convolving with a test function. Some representations might make things more convenient, of course (e.g. the distributional derivative being represented by the derivative of a representative). Incidentally, the dirac delta distribution isn't differentiable either, unless you restrict to test functions that are differentiable at zero. (I'm not sure if you need differentiable eveywhere to make sense of differentiating a distribution)

Comment: it is differentiable in a sense. At least, the notion of derivative of dirac delta (and further derivatives) is widely used. See my answer for the for that I found is employed in non-standard analysis. Its derivative thus would be $-\frac{2 w^3 z e^{-(w z)^2}}{\sqrt{\pi }}$

Comment: @Anixx: I don't mean to imply it's a bad representation; functions of that shape are particularly useful in the context of Schwartz distributions due to their nice properties with respect to the Fourier transform, so in such contexts it is surely a useful choice of representation.

Comment: The upshot would seem to be: what _defines_ the Dirac delta are its properties under integration. So we should hardly be surprised if there are (infinitely) many representations in NS analysis any more than in the standard case. But it also doesn't exclude some reps being more useful than others.

Comment: I had forgotten, but there is a nice representation of the derivative in the style above: $$\delta'(x) = \begin{cases} H^2 & x \in [0,1/H] \\ -H^2 & x \in [-1/H,0] \\ 0 & |x| > 1/H \end{cases}$$ Possibly needing some care, I think you could define the derivative in general for a distribution as $d'(x) = (d(x) - d(x-\epsilon))/\epsilon$

Comment: @Hurkyl it seems you confused the right and left parts of the function in this definition of derivative. Its derivative should be positive at negative part and negative at positive area, otherwise its integral would be negative. Also note that this definition has a major disadvantage: delta is even function so its derivative shoud be odd. And also it should be 0 in x=0 because delta has maximum there.

Comment: @Anixx: Ack, I did mean $d(x-\epsilon) - d(x)$. The value of an integrand (when it's an ordinary function) at individual points doesn't matter; such differences go away when you take the integral. Sliding the nonstandard part left or right doesn't matter either, although if you really cared about symmetry you could use something like $(d(x - \epsilon) - d(x + \epsilon)) / (2\epsilon)$

Comment: Incidentally, there's no reason why the representative of $\delta$ has to have a maximum at zero -- or even have a large value there. Another perfectly good representative is $$\delta(x) = \begin{cases} H & x \in [3/H, 4/H] \\ 0 & x < 3/H \vee x > 4/H \end{cases} $$ If we're in a situation where we get to pick the representative, we can pick what we like, but knowing counterexamples like this is rather important if we are faced with a problem where we are merely given an otherwise unknown function that represents the $\delta$: we can't assume it resembles our favorite choices at all!

Comment: @Hurkyl if derivative of delta is negative at x<0 and positive at x>0, this means that delta is non-positive around and in zero, which would not give positive integral. It is evident you made a mistake.

Comment: Delta is even function so its derivative should be odd. That is zero at x=0.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer.

$$\delta(x)=\frac{\omega e^{-(\omega x)^2}}{\sqrt{\pi }}$$

And its integral, Heaviside Theta is

$$\theta(x)=\frac12\operatorname{erf}(\omega x)+1/2$$

As such,

$$\delta(0)=\frac{\omega}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$

Comment: I can certainly believe that those work (and they're evidently consistent with $\theta'(x)=\delta(x)$). But to call that _the_ answer would seem to suppose that no other formulations are possible, which surprises me given the multitude of nascent delta functions encountered in practice. Is the situation different in non-standard analysis?

Comment: @Semiclassical this is what is non-standard analysis. And also $\delta(0)=\frac{\omega}{\sqrt{\pi}}$